# Ajuda em java com conceito de como relacionar classes

Tags: java

```
package br.edu.utfpr.exer05;

public class Porta {
    boolean aberta;
    String cor;
    double dimensaoX, dimensaoY, dimensaoZ;

    void abre() {
        this.aberta = true;
    }
    void fecha() {
        this.aberta = false;
    }
    void pinta(String cor) {
        this.cor = cor;
    }
    boolean estaAberta() {
        boolean estaAberta = false;
        if(aberta == true) estaAberta = true;
        return estaAberta;
    }

}

package br.edu.utfpr.exer05;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Edificio {
    String cor;
    int totalDePortas;
    int totalDeAndares;
    ArrayList<Porta> portas = new ArrayList<Porta>();

    void pinta(String cor) {
        this.cor = cor;
    }

    int quantasPortasEstaoAbertas() {
        int qtdPortasAbertas = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<portas.size(); i++) {
            portas.get(i);
            if(portas.get(i).estaAberta() == true) {
                qtdPortasAbertas++;
            }
        }
        return qtdPortasAbertas;
    }

    void adicionaPorta(Porta porta) {
        this.portas.add(porta);
    }

    int totalDePortas() {
        return this.portas.size();
    }

    void adicionaAndar() {
        this.totalDeAndares = totalDeAndares += 1;
    }

    int totalDeAndares() {
        return this.totalDeAndares;
    }
}

package br.edu.utfpr.exer05;

public class Casa {
    String cor;
    Porta porta1, porta2, porta3;

    void pinta(String cor) {
        this.cor = cor;
    }

    int quantasPortasEstaoAbertas() {
        int qtdPortasAbertas=0;
        if(porta1.estaAberta() == true) qtdPortasAbertas++;
        if(porta2.estaAberta() == true) qtdPortasAbertas++;
        if(porta3.estaAberta() == true) qtdPortasAbertas++;
        return qtdPortasAbertas;
    }

    int totalDePortas() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Conceitualmente uma casa é um edifício. Esta é a intenção? O nome está correto? Ou na verdade queria está usando esse nome para uma edificação com andares? Eles são coisas distintas mesmo? Fora isto não entendi qual é seu problema? Qual sua dúvida? O que seria "usar atributo da casa para implementar o edificio"? Realmente está esquisto `Casa` ter 3 variáveis para as portas e `Edificio` ter um *array* (ainda que usado de forma errada).

Comment: Crie a classe Edificio com os Atributos: cor, totalDePortas, totalDeAndares, portas[] e métodos: void pinta(String cor), int quantasPortasEstaoAbertas(), void adicionaPorta(Porta p), int totalDePortas(), void adicionarAndar(), int totalDeAndares()
Para testar, crie um edifício, pinte‐o.
Crie seis portas e coloque‐as no edifício através do método adicionaPorta, abra e feche‐as como desejar.

Comment: Vou repetir, não estou vendo dúvida alguma aí.

Comment: Bigown, os meus professores de php e c, passaram uma burduada de coisas e o de java passo herança de classe, depois do edifício eu ainda tenho que criar uma classe imóvel como classe pai e colocar a casa e o edifício como filho, estou tentando encaixar isso na cabeça, pois tenho prova disso hoje, se já tiver conteúdo sobre isso e puder me passar agradeço, :))))

Comment: bigown a minha duvida e que, na casa eu usei Porta porta1 = new Porta(); para criar portas na casa e para criar portas no edificio, eu nao estou entendedo

Comment: Na classe porta eu tinha um numero fixo de atributo como porta, eram 3 portas, já na classe edifício essa quantidade são n portas. como fazer ? :/

Comment: Primeiro, deveria ter criado a classe `Imovel` primeiro. Aí vai ser compatibilizar as duas. Então e certa forma qualquer resposta para esta pergunta pode não servir para nada dependendo do que mude depois. Isto tudo ainda está confuso demais. Eu prefiro não responder porque a base está toda errada. Tem que começar de novo fazendo o certo. Aí quem sabe poderia não misturar o objeto com a GUI. Este é outro erro conceitual que complica também.

Comment: no caso voce me aconselha a ir do final para o inicio ? pois a sequencia que meu professor recomendo foi

criar classe porta - usar metodo main para testar os metodos da classe porta como abrir, fechar e pintar. 
criar classe casa - declarar atributo porta , referenciando a classe porta , criar 3 portas e usar metodos de abrir e pintar nela.
criar classe edifcio -  ? to em duvida nesse ja com os atributos

Comment: A classe `Porta` é independente. O problema é começar uma herança pelas classes filhas, isto não costuma dar certo, principalmente sem experiência.

Comment: classe edificio -- o meu professor recomendo, para que eu crie um método void AdicionarPorta(Porta p ){};
E dai eu tenho o atributo portas[]; // que e um vetor e ele vai passar de parametro para que eu possa adicionar as portas ... e isso o conceito ? bigown ?

Comment: Entendi a porta não vai ter relacionamento, só imóvel , casa e edifício (prédio);

Comment: Relacionamento vai, não vai ter herança.

Comment: bigown eu posso criar uma variável n , e pedir para o usuário digitar o numero de portas do edifício e então eu faço um for para 1 < n e coloco para que portas[] tenha n elementos, assim eu terei o numero de portas q o usuário deseja, certo ?

Comment: isso bigown rsrs o que eu queria dizer, confundo ainda relacionamento com herança. rsrs

Comment: Certo. Pode fazer isto.

Comment: vou tentar fazer, obrigado brother :))

Comment: pode dar uma olhada bigown e ver se esta bom ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu resolveria esse problema ai de outra forma.

Classe porta:

```
public class Porta {
    boolean aberta;
    String cor;
    double dimensaoX, dimensaoY, dimensaoZ;

    public void Porta(boolean aberta, String cor, double dimensaoX, double dimensaoY, double dimensaoZ){
        this.aberta = aberta;
        this.cor = cor;
        this.dimensaoX = dimensaoX;
        this.dimensaoY = dimensaoY;
        this.dimensaoZ = dimensaoZ;
    }

    public void Porta(){
        //Atributos padrões apenas para inicialização. Poderiam ser quaisquer outros.
        aberta = false;
        cor = "azul";
        dimensaoX = 2.00;
        dimensaoY = 1.00;
        dimensaoZ = 0.5;
    }

    void abre() {
        this.aberta = true;
    }

    void fecha() {
        this.aberta = false;
    }

    void pinta(String cor) {
        this.cor = cor;
    }

    boolean estaAberta() {
        return aberta;
    }
}
```

É muito recomendado que você sempre tenha um construtor pra inicializar as variáveis. Você pode ter mais de um construtor, quando você não coloca nenhum, o compilador do java coloca um vazio.

Do jeito que ta agora, mesmo quando você instanciar a classe Porta com o construtor padrão, você não vai correr o risco de levantar NullPointer, pois no construtor padrão já é feita a inicialização das variáveis antes de começar a usa-las.

```
boolean estaAberta() {
        boolean estaAberta = false;
        if(aberta == true) estaAberta = true;
        return estaAberta;
    }
```

Isso oque você fez não faz o menor sentido, e é um erro muito comum quando se está aprendendo a programar. Funciona, mas é muito feio.
Você quer um método que te diga se a porta está aberta ou não e você tem uma variável 'aberta' que te diz isso, agora, porque não retornar ela simplesmente? Ela é true ou false, se estiver aberta vai retornar true se estiver fechada vai retornar False, acabou, não precisa fazer isso tudo oque você fez.

```
if(aberta == true)...
```

Isso também é muito feio e extremamente desnecessário. A variável 'aberta' já é um boolean, não precisa ser comparada com false ou true, porque ela ja possui um dos dois valores, bastaria fazer:

```
if(aberta)...
```

Se aberta for igual a true, ele vai entrar no if, se não for, não vai.

Classe Edificio:

```
public class Edificio {
    String cor;
    int totalDeAndares;
    ArrayList<Porta> portas;

    public void Edificio(String cor, int totalDeAndares, ArrayList<Porta> portas){
        this.cor = cor;
        this.totalDeAndares = totalDeAndares;
        this.portas = portas;
    }

    public void Edificio(){
        //Valores padrao.
        portas = new ArrayList<>();
        cor = "azul";
        totalDeAndares = 1;
    }

    void pinta(String cor) {
        this.cor = cor;
    }

    int quantasPortasEstaoAbertas() {
        int qtdPortasAbertas = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<portas.size(); i++) {
            if(portas.get(i).estaAberta()) {
                qtdPortasAbertas++;
            }
        }
        return qtdPortasAbertas;
    }

    void adicionaPorta(Porta porta) {
        this.portas.add(porta);
    }

    int totalDePortas() {
        return this.portas.size();
    }

    void adicionaAndar() {
        this.totalDeAndares++;
    }

    int totalDeAndares() {
        return this.totalDeAndares;
    }
}
```

O atributo totalDePortas não faz sentido algum, já que você consegue obter com o tamanho do ArrayList. A não ser que ele signifique o numero máximo de portas, mas como vc não falou nada, considero que não.

```
if(portas.get(i).estaAberta() == true)...
```

Isso eu ja comentei anteriormente.

Classe Casa:

Essa é a parte mais errada no seu código. As coisas mais importantes em Orientação à Objetos é o Polimorfismo e Herança.

Casa é um tipo de Edificio, logo, eu posso dizer que a classe Edíficio é mãe de Casa.

Minha classe Casa é isso tudo ai.
Olha só:

```
public class Casa extends Edificio {

    public void Casa(){
        super.Edificio();
    }
}
```

Agora vai no Main ai e faz isso:

```
Edificio casa = new Casa();

casa.pinta("Laranja");

System.out.println(casa.cor);
```

O resultado vai ser: `Laranja`

Mágica? Não, é Polimorfismo + Herança.

Sabe porque isso aconteceu? Porque como casa é um tipo de edifício, eu estendi a Classe cada para Edifício.
TODOS, eu disse TODOS, os atributos e métodos da classe Edifício agora também são da Classe Casa sem você precisar escrever em Casa.

Recomendo que você brinque ai com as classes e veja o tamanho do poder do polimorfismo e da herança.

Qualquer dúvida é só perguntar.